# New HD - Can't get USB boot working to install Ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb, windows-7, hard-drive

Here's my setup:
-Windows 7 (legit)
- Acer Revo Nettop (it's my htpc)
-Hard drive is failing
- Followed this article:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows
- When i take out the dying drive, insert the new drive, turn on computer with newly created bootable USB drive it starts up and then just sits on:

SYSLINUX Copyright 1997-2008 Some Guy blah blah
_ (blinking cursor)

What am I doing wrong?  All I want to do is get Ubuntu onto a brand new hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

Did you [MD5 test](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) the `.iso` image that you used to create the USB flash drive? If not, you should do that now, and see if it was corrupted (e.g., during download). If it was, you'll have to download the `.iso` image again and start over.

If that checks out OK, then try writing the USB flash drive with [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) instead, and see if that works any better.

If neither of those work, please edit your question to indicate this, and also to tell us what specific model of Acer Revo you have.